# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains

Tags: django, autocomplete, jquery-select2

I am creating a Cascading dropdown and keep getting a Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains error. I have tried several suggestions under this subject on Stackoverflow but none seems to address my case. I am using autocomplete

I have two models.

```
class BusinessCategory(BaseModel):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Category name'))
   status = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class SubBusinessCategory(BaseModel):
    business_category = models.ForeignKey(BusinessCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And this is the setup of how it has been used in my model forms

```
class BusinessBoardingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """On boarding business form for Business Application"""
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset = BusinessCategory.objects.all(),
        label=u"Business Category",
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            data_url='/admin/directories/businesscategory/autocomplete/',
            model=BusinessCategory,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
        )
    ) # This one works alright.

    sub_category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset = SubBusinessCategory.objects.all(),
        label=u"Sub Category",
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            data_url='/admin/directories/subbusinesscategory/autocomplete/',
            model=SubBusinessCategory,
            search_fields=['business_category__name__icontains'],
            dependent_fields={'business_category': 'name'},
            max_results=500,
        )
    )
```

I am getting the lookup error at the Sub category. What am I missing?